# How can I simulate a responsive website like desktop in mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a responsive website, in which I need to add a button "view classic version (Desktop)". The problem is that the site was made in responsive format and I can not redo it in the mobile version (both, mobile version and desktop version separated). Is there any way I could simulate a size of 1200px inside my mobile device (JavaScript or jQuery)?

e.g. The website is using Bootstrap 3

Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you just set a class on the `<body>` of `.desktop`, and style a `min-width: 1200px` on it?

Comment: So, this is a good idea but they don't want to update CSS, I need to do this so that I do not have to add more CSS, since creating the classes in the body I could, but in the same way I would have to change the CSS to adapt the versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is necessary change the metatag viewport to desktop.

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  var mobileWidth =  (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
  var viewport = (mobileWidth > 360) ? 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' : 'width=1200';
  $("meta[name=viewport]").attr('content', viewport);
}).resize();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```